# Reading JSON Data returned from REST API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api

The following code is supposed to simply alert me with the value that I am wishing to get from a JSON file. The problem is it doesn't give me anything back :(. Below is the link for the JSON file:

```
https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=5.39&lat=51.57
```

In case you don't know, the [Soil Grids API](https://rest.soilgrids.org) is an API used for giving you soil insight on a certain latitude and longitude of land mass.

I have to admit, I don't know what is wrong. Below is my code:

```js
var soil = new XMLHttpRequest();

function testFunction (){
  soil.open("REST", "https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=5.39&lat=51.57", false);
  soil.send(null);
  var r = JSON.parse(soil.response);
  var majorreal = r.properties.TAXNWRBMajor;
  alert(majorreal);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="testFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Whenever the program is run, I get a send error with the XMLHttpRequest...

```
"Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on
'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://rest.soilgrids.org/query
lon=5.39&lat=51.57'.",
```

Any help would be appreciated ;).

Comment: Why are you passing *REST* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `REST` method (*see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open*).

Using `GET` works.

```js
var soil = new XMLHttpRequest();

function testFunction (){
  soil.open("GET", "https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=5.39&lat=51.57", false);
  soil.send(null);
  var r = JSON.parse(soil.response);
  var majorreal = r.properties.TAXNWRBMajor;
  alert(majorreal);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="testFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Also there is no reason to use synchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

A common convention is to follow the pattern below. This allows you to do something with the result when its is done by checking for the ready state property.

```
function testFunction (){
 var soil = new XMLHttpRequest();
    soil.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    };
   soil.open("GET", "https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=5.39&lat=51.57", false);
   soil.send(null);
 }
```